# Mac Software to Search / Replace within a Project

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, search, html

0
down vote
I haven't been able to find what I need.

For me. A project is a client. Their entire html / css / js website.

I need to maintain various search / replace values at a project level.

Select a Project.

And a list of project specific search / replace (that I created) entries appear.

If I open a different project… it may have similar search / replace values… but they are not related to any other project. It's literally a different website / property.

I’ve tried numerous applications that allow me to perform search / replaces but most don’t allow me to save the patterns (to eliminate re-typing 100’s of patterns every month)

and I’ve only found 1 (MassReplaceIt) that allows to save the changes at a project level…

Managing the patterns with MassReplaceIt is extremely cumbersome when you have 50 projects you are working on every month. Performing the same changes to each project - every month / over and over.

I want to be able to open a project… Add / Edit / Remove / Enable / Disable / Execute a list of Search / Replace patterns.

Then I want to open a different project and do the exact same thing (with it's own project values) - without affect any other project.

This would save me days and days of work every month.

And it needs to be Mac based.

Anyway / any software to do this ?

Comment: BBEdit (paid app) and TextWrangler (free version, derived from BBEdit) can preform Multi-File Search however it's Find History only holds ~15 entries and I see nothing in the Preferences to change that. Although that doesn't necessarily mean it can't be changed. Would probably have to check Support at the website.

Comment: @marked. Where was this question previously asked ? If you are referring to the question I posted in a different question - I was told - to create a new question.

Comment: @marked. If you are referring to the top of the page - where it says "The question already has an answer here"... No - This doesn't answer my question. And if you noticed... that's where I originally asked the question - and was told to create a new question. Please kindly remove the Duplicate tag.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to try free 'Find and Replace' utility?

Web site: http://findandreplace.sourceforge.net

Comment: I just downloaded it and when I tried opening it, it crashed and I do have java installed and my other java apps run just fine. Not worth troubleshooting because I'd rather use an app that does not require java when other apps can do the same thing without it. That said, I'd rather use BBEdit or TextWrangler.

Comment: @ranklord. Thanks for responding. Yes - I've tried this utility. It does the basics but doesn't do the project level as I really need it. I can write this application in php or cold fusion... but I'm trying to avoid this due to a lack of time. MassReplaceIt from Hex Monkey is the closest I've found to do what I need... but the interface is not that great. The developer built the app for his own needs - which are similar to mine. It just doesn't quite go far enough in the project management aspect.

Comment: Ok. Hope, you'll find the solution for your needs.

Comment: @user3556416 MassReplaceIt is great, thanks for the comment